# Weblogic 12c - unpacked war issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy the application on `weblogic` `12c`. Application is not the exploded one i.e. it is the unpacked ear file.

> Exception -  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.AegisType

Note: Weblogic 10 does not face any issue with same application irrespective exploded or not.
Weblogic 12C is able to deploy exploded one without any issue.

Comment: This error really means that the container can't find the `AegisType` class for some reason.  Can you inspect the EAR and check that this class is really there in the correct place?  Then, check the exploded folder, which still works on 12C.  Is it there too?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the pom file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-aegis</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Depending on what else you are you using, you may need to add the following as well:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.abdera</groupId>
            <artifactId>abdera-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3-redhat-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
```